# How to make a selection in two parts

Tags: jquery, syntax

I'm looking for the correct syntax to make a "double selection" in JQuery. I tried the following code but it doesn't work :

```
$('#list li').last().$('img').attr({ src : dataUrl, alt : file.name });
```

I get this error :

```
 Error: TypeError: $(...).last(...).$ is not a function
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#list li').last().find('img').attr({ src : dataUrl, alt : file.name });
```

?

It will select all the images inside the last `li`

The same a bit more compact:

```
$('img', '#list li:last')
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('firest selector, second selector')` if you want to select all elements matching `first selector` and all elements matching `second selector`

or

`$('#list li:last-child img').attr({ src : dataUrl, alt : file.name });`